Why is the set of linear combinations of irreps closed under matrix products?
I'm studying Barry Simon's book on representation theory. There's this one result he proves stating that the set of linear combinations of $D_{ij}^{(\alpha)}$ is closed under taking products. The $D_{ij}^{(\alpha)}$ are simply the matrix realizations he takes for the each irrep $\alpha \in \widehat{G}$. What we want to prove is that
$$
D_{ij}^{(\alpha)}(x)D_{kl}^{(\beta)}(x) = \sum_{m,p,q} c_{ij;kl;pq}^{\alpha\beta m}D_{pq}^{(\gamma_m)}.
$$
He approaches this through the tensor product representation. If $W^{(\alpha)}$ and $V^{(\beta)}$ are irreps, $W^{(\alpha)} \otimes V^{(\beta)}$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of irreps $\bigoplus_\gamma n_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma U^{(\gamma)}$, where the $n_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma$ are called the Clebsch-Gordan integers, representing how many times each $U^{(\gamma)}$ appears in the direct sum. He then states that by making the unitary equivalences precise we get the desired result.
I believe writing the details should not be difficult, as it involves writing $W^{(\alpha)} = T_\alpha D^{(\alpha)}T_\alpha^* $, with $T_\alpha$ unitary for each of $W^\alpha,V^\beta, U^\gamma$. Then one would get something like
$$
D^{(\alpha)} \otimes D^{(\beta)} = M^* \left(\bigoplus_m n_{\alpha\beta}^m T_{\gamma_m}D^{\gamma_m}T_{\gamma_m}^* \right)M.
$$
I'm stumbled when it comes to expressing the following details precisely. Can anyone help? I'm attaching a screenshot of the theorem here. 

In fact, matrix coefficients are an orthogonal basis for the space of functions on a (finite) group. This is one version of Schur Orthogonality.

Yes! But this is one of the results he uses to prove exactly that so, unfortunately for my project, that's not the answer I'm looking for.  He proves orthogonality using Schur's lemma and then proves that the $D_{ij}$ verify a more general result for completeness and thus generate the space of functions.

You can prove orthogonality of (distinct) matrix coefficients using only Schur's lemma IIRC. Then you can deduce the matrix coefficients form a basis for the space of functions on $G$ by a dimension argument (when $G$ is finite).

Alternative approach:
$G$ acts on the space of functions on $G$  as follows $(g\cdot \phi)(x) \colon = \phi(x g)$.  Now consider the set of those $\phi$ such that the span of $(g\cdot \phi)_{g\in G}$ is finite dimensional.  You can see that we get exactly the space generated by the matrix coefficients of finite dimensional ($\&$ irreducible-- if $G$ finite, or compact, $k=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) representations.  It is also easy to see that this space is closed under product.

I think I found a solution:
Precising unitary equivalences we have
\begin{align*}
        W^{(\alpha)}\otimes V^{(\beta)} = (T_\alpha \otimes T_\beta)^* (D^{(\alpha)} \otimes D^{(\beta)}) (T_\alpha \otimes T_\beta) &= \left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M n_{\alpha\beta}^m T_mD^{(\gamma_m)}T_m^*\right) \\
        &= \left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M T_m\right)\left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M n_{\alpha\beta}^m D^{(\gamma_m)}\right)\left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M T_m\right)^*.
\end{align*}
So, if we write $T_{\alpha\beta} = (T_\alpha \otimes T_\beta)\left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M T_m\right)$ and we take the corresponding element in the tensor product we have
$$\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
    D_{ij}^{(\alpha)}(x)D_{kl}^{(\beta)}(x) = \langle ik|D^{(\alpha)}(x) \otimes D^{(\beta)}(x)|jl\rangle = \langle ik|T_{\alpha\beta} \left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M n_{\alpha\beta}^m D^{(\gamma_m)}(x)\right) T_{\alpha\beta}^*|jl\rangle.
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}$$
Now we introduce twice the identity for each block $\sum_p^{d_{\gamma_m}} |p\rangle\langle p| $, we then have
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
    D_{ij}^{(\alpha)}(x)D_{kl}^{(\beta)}(x) &= \langle ik|T_{\alpha\beta} \left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M n_{\alpha\beta}^m \left(\sum_p^{d_{\gamma_m}}|p\rangle\langle p|\right)D^{(\gamma_m)}(x)\left(\sum_q^{d_{\gamma_m}}|q\rangle\langle q|\right)\right) T_{\alpha\beta}^*|jl\rangle \\
    &= \langle ik|T_{\alpha\beta} \left(\bigoplus_{m=1}^M \sum_{p,q}^{d_{\gamma_m}}n_{\alpha\beta}^m |p\rangle\langle q|\langle p|D^{(\gamma_m)}(x)|q\rangle\right) T_{\alpha\beta}^*|jl\rangle \\
    &= \sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{p,q}^{d_{\gamma_m}}n_{\alpha\beta}^m\langle ik|T_{\alpha\beta}|p\rangle\langle q|T_{\alpha\beta}^*| jl\rangle D_{pq}^{(\gamma_m)}(x) = \sum_{m;p,q}c_{ij;kl;pq}^{\alpha\beta m}D_{pq}^{(\gamma_m)}(x).
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
Please, let me know if anyone finds a mistake or inaccuracy.
